# excel sendkeys for popup

Tags: excel, vba

Am I able to bypass the attached image? or run a SendKeys "{ENTER}" command. (if so I couldn't get it to work)

[image]

also how can I loop this to open a pdf for each cell from `A9 to last`?

```
Sub Cutsheets()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim finalrow As Integer    

finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

If Not Application.Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("A9:A" & finalrow)) Is Nothing Then

ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "P:\ESO\1790-ORL\OUC\_Materials\Material Cutsheets\" & ActiveCell & ".pdf"
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}", True

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

thanks for any help

Comment: you can add that location as a trusted site in excel and you will not get that popup

Comment: Does adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to the beginning suppress that?

Comment: @BruceWayne it's a security prompt so it can't be suppressed with VBA.

Comment: Either add the location as a trusted location, or copy the files _to_ a trusted location at the start of your code. It's bad practice to try and code _around_ security features. Also steer clear of `SendKeys` unless you absolutely know which active window will receive the message that you send. You can send messages to any window using WinAPI, but it's a million times easier to just move the files/add a trusted location.

Comment: That location is already in my trusted places and `allow trusted locations on my network` is also checked.